# ¿Cómo generar un csv correctamente en Django?

Tags: python, django, csv

Estoy tratando de generar un archivo `.csv` en django lo hago a partir de esta data:

```
listaFinal = 
[
   [
      {
         "-":"LIBROS"
      },
      {
         "":"Zoología: Fauna de Ecuador y el Mundo",
         "Editorial":"Editorial UTPL",
         "Año":2011,
         "Páginas":468,
         "Tipo Libro":51
      },
      {
         "":"Manejo adaptativo de ganadería sostenible en el ecosistema páramo",
         "Editorial":"EDILOJA",
         "Año":2019,
         "Páginas":200,
         "Tipo Libro":103
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "-":"ARTICULOS"
      },
      {
         "":"Taeniasis-cysticercosis in Southern Ecuador: Assessment of infection status using multiple laboratory diagnostic tools",
         "Link Articulo":"http://dx.doi.org/10.1590/S0074-02762006000700012\\xa0",
         "issn":"740276",
         "nombre_conferencia":"",
         "Keywords":"cysticercosis; ecuador; enzyme linked immunosorbent assay; enzyme;linked immunoelectrotransfer blot; polymerase chain reaction; restricted fragment length polymerase; taenia solium; taeniasis",
         "Revista":"Memorias do Instituto Oswaldo Cruz",
         "Fecha Publicación":"2006-09-06",
         "Índice":"ISI",
         "País":"Otro",
         "Año":2006
      },
      {
         "":"Seroprevalence and risk factors associated with Brucella seropositivity in dairy and mixed cattle herds from Ecuador",
         "Link Articulo":"https://www.scopus.com/inward/record.uri?eid=2-s2.0-85029903877&doi=10.1007%2fs11250-017-1421-6&partnerID=40&md5=cd159b329f75a30ca929cdb8ecec44b0\r\n",
         "issn":"00494747",
         "nombre_conferencia":"",
         "Keywords":"Brucella; cattle; dairy; seropositivity; risk factors; Ecuador",
         "Revista":"Tropical Animal Health and Production",
         "Fecha Publicación":"2017-09-26",
         "Índice":"Scopus",
         "País":"",
         "Año":2018
      }
   ]
]
```

En mis `views` tengo una función que hace lo siguiente:

```py
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')  
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="file.csv"'  
    writer = csv.writer(response)  
    
    for lista in listaFinal:
        print(lista)
        for i in lista:
            writer.writerow(k for k, v in i.items()) 
            writer.writerow(v for k, v in i.items())


    return response
```

El problema que tengo es que el csv se genera de esta forma
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se me crea los titulos **Editorial, País, Año, Paginas, Link Articulo, etc...** por cada libro o cada articulo que tengo, se que estoy algo en el for al momento de escribir en el `csv` pero no se como hacerlo.

```py
writer.writerow(k for k, v in i.items()) 
writer.writerow(v for k, v in i.items())
```

Mi pregunta es. ¿Cómo puedo generar el csv solo con una cabecera o titulo para los libros o articulos en lugar de que se repita por cada uno de ellos? Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias de antemano.

Comment: si utilizas pandas todo se vuelve más fácil, ya que pandas acepta diccionarios para crear DataFrames, luego es convertido a csv

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @Christian, revisando tu json o tu data, se puede apreciar que son dos arreglos( al cual le falta una coma), posiblemente eso este afectando, puedes utilizar una pagina para pasear y ver tu error https://jsonparseronline.com

Answer (score 0):

Si de hecho, usar pandas seria lo mas adecuado con tu información generando diccionarios, un ejemplo seria lo siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd
main_dict = {"campo_1":["hola"],"campo_2":["mundo"]}
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(main_dict)
# Procedemos almacenarlos en una lista
libros = []
libros.append(dataframe)
# Procedemos a unir los dataframes
gen_df = 0
for libro in libros:
    if gen_df is 0:
        gen_df = libro
    else:
        gen_df = pd.concat([gen_df , libro], axis=0)
gen_df.to_csv("hola.csv")
```

Si tienes mas dudas sobre como proceder y modificar un dataframe leido por pandas te recomiendo visitar la [documentación](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html)